# git merge doesn't work as expected (present conflict) when changing file name and its path

Tags: git, git-merge

Let’s say I have 2 branches : A and B (let’s presume B is a split from A)

In branch  A, I have changed the content of a file `root/blabla/ariel1.txt`

In branch B, I have changed the path to `ariel1.txt` and rename it, so now it is called `ariel2.txt`, and the path to it is: `root/yadayada/ariel2.txt`

Now, I decide to merge branch A into branch B.

How does git knows to merge the changes `ariel1.txt` (in branch A) to `ariel2.txt` (in branch B)?

I encountered in such case , and git didn’t know how to handle it correctly. any ideas how to overcome such case?

Comment: Git does not track renames or moves. It has heuristics that try to figure out whether an add + a delete is really a rename or a move, but depending on the amount of changes done to the file in the same commit, it may or may not succeed. Your best option when doing stuff like this is to move and rename the file *in a separate commit*. Don't change the contents of the file in this commit, just move and/or rename it. This way, git should easily be able to figure out that it was moved/renamed and act accordingly.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Doing the move and rename in a separate commit does not help if there is just a single merge operation. It does help if the commit that moves and renames is merged separatly in advance.

Comment: Adding to Lasse's explanation, if you rebase your branch first, the merge is a simple fast-forward one and won't conflict. You can add `--no-ff` if you want the separate merge commit though.

Comment: Unless that single merge operation squashes the commits, it should help. In my experience it *does* help, to separate moves and renames into their own commits. For instance, in .NET projects, if I want to move a class to a different namespace, I move the file into the right folder according to the namespace structure, in one commit, and then fix the namespace declaration inside the file, in another commit. This leaves me able to follow the history of files. Only time this has failed and left git confused for me was when both branches did this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't store renames and copies. Instead, it checks to see if files have similar content. If branch A changed the content too much, Git won't recognize it as a rename. You can control what it considers a rename with [--find-renames](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-find-renamesltngt).

Comment: But it should raise conflict, no?

Comment: @arielma Only if the there are textual conflicts. If one side did just a rename without edits, then the other side's edits are incorporated without triggering a conflict.

Comment: @arielma If Git doesn't recognize that branchA's ariel1.txt is branchB's ariel2.txt are the same file, they will not conflict. That's obviously not good. Problem like this are often solved with a different branch mangement process. I'd need to know more about your process to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> How does git knows to merge the changes ariel1.txt (in branch A) to ariel2.txt (in branch B)?

It doesn't. Of course, *you* do. You have a notion of independently moving or renaming the file, as an action orthogonal to editing the file; but Git does not.

As Git sees it, in one branch the file was edited; in the other branch it was *deleted*. Those are conflicting fates, because being edited implies *not* being deleted; and Git rightly turns to you to resolve the conflict.

Solution: Resolve it and move on. Merge conflicts are not bad or uncommon; learn to cope with them.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention it, but git doesn’t reflect it as conflict...

Comment: Okay, in that case please update your question with actual actions and observations. Provide a [mcve] as well, starting with `git init` in an empty directory.